# How to replace file_get_contents that has 3 parameters e.g: file_get_content($url, false, $context) with curl

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

I am trying to configure google reCAPTCHA v3 on my website and because of the https, I am not getting a response using  file_get_contents. I need to replace that with curl but I don't know how to implement that using 3 parameters.

```
$url="googleverify.com";

$options = array(

        'ssl' => array(
          'verify_peer'=>false,
          'verify_peer_name'=>false,
          'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
          'method'  => 'POST',
          'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
      );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the error....

```
$context  = stream_context_create($options);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $options);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = curl_exec($ch);

  print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      'verify_peer'=>false,
      'verify_peer_name'=>false,
```

translates to

```
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>0,
));
```

and

```
      'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
```

translates to

```
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    )
));
```

(and no, do not use \r\n with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER) and

```
     'method'  => 'POST',
```

translates to

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
```

and

```
  'content' => http_build_query($data)
```

translates to

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
```

and finally, putting them all together we get:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>0,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ),
    CURLOPT_POST=>true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>http_build_query($data)
));
```

Comment: @Dharman good rule of thumb (and good that you commented on OP's post about it), but my translation is accurate